# Why are images overlapping in CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to build a product page with CSS Grid. For some reason my images keep overlapping, instead of being positioned below each other.

I mimicked my code (without all the drupal fluf) in the code below. I have the same issue there. I tried with a single grid and also with grid in a grid (as in my example)

https://jsfiddle.net/e28mc4f5/1/

```css
#mygrid {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: auto;
 grid-template-areas: 
  "images title"
  "images model"
  "images price"
  ;
}

#mygrid .items  {
 background-color: red;
 grid-area: images;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 100px 200px;
 grid-template-rows: 100px 100px auto;
 grid-template-areas: 
  "thumbs main"
    "thumbs main"
    "thumbs main"
  ;
}

#mygrid .items .item  {
 grid-area: thumbs;

}

#mygrid .items .item img{
  //why are there overlapping??
 width: 100px;
 height: auto;
  
}

#mygrid .items .item:first-child  {
 grid-area: main;
   
}

#mygrid .items .item:first-child img{
 width: 200px;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="mygrid">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cities">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=info>MY TITLE</div>
  <div class=info>My Description</div>
  <div class=prijs>My Price</div>
  
</div>
```

I'm trying to place all images (except the first) in the first grid column named "thumbs".  (this works but fall over each other)

And I'm placing the first image in a second column with a bigger size. (this works)

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic, but I've been trying (and googling) for hours. Maybe another pair of eyes can enlighten me.

---

This is a single-grid version. Here the issue is that the first image will not put itself in the correct location.

https://jsfiddle.net/wrpt5g3b/1/

```css
#mygrid {
 display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 3fr;
 grid-template-rows: 25px 25px 25px auto;
  
 grid-template-areas: 
  "aside main model"
  "aside main price"
  "aside main input"
  "aside . ."
  ;
}

#mygrid .items  {
}

#mygrid .items .item  {
 grid-area: aside;
}

#mygrid .items .item img{
 width: 100px;
 height: auto;
  
}

#mygrid .items .item:first-child  {
 grid-area: main;   //why is this ignoring it's place?
  justify-self: stretch;
}

#mygrid .items .item:first-child img{
 width: 200px;
 //height: auto;
}
#mygrid .title {
  grid-area: model;
 justify-self: stretch;
} 

#mygrid .info {
  grid-area: input;
 justify-self: stretch;
} 

#mygrid .price {
  grid-area: price;
 justify-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div id="mygrid">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=title>MY TITLE</div>
  <div class=info>My Description</div>
  <div class=price>My Price</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are applying the same grid area name to all image containers.

Each `.item` element is named `thumbs`.

***Your HTML***

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cities">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature">
  </div>
</div>
```

***Your CSS***

```
#mygrid .items  {
   background-color: red;
   grid-area: images;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 100px 200px;
   grid-template-rows: 100px 100px auto;
   grid-template-areas: 
                        "thumbs main"
                        "thumbs main"
                        "thumbs main"
   ;
}

.item {
   grid-area: thumbs;
}

.item:first-child  {
   grid-area: main;
}

.item img {
   width: 100px;
   height: auto;
}

.item:first-child img {
   width: 200px;
   height: auto;
}
```

***Here's what's happening***

- The first image container is named `main`, overriding `thumbs`. This container is placed in the second column, in accordance with your `grid-template-areas` rule.
- The second, third and fourth image containers are named `thumbs`. Because all three elements have the same name, the first two are ignored and the last one is rendered ([per the rules of HTML parsing](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing), which is based generally on the order of appearance in the source document).
- So, ultimately, there are no overlapping images. What you're getting is image1 in the second column and image4 in the first column.
- image1 is taller than image4 because it has double the width (per your CSS).

***Solution***

Give each item a unique grid area name.

```css
#mygrid {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: auto;
 grid-template-areas: 
  "images title"
  "images model"
  "images price"
  ;
}

.items {
 background-color: red;
 grid-area: images;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 100px 200px;
 grid-template-rows: 100px 100px auto;
 grid-template-areas: 
              "thumbs2 main"
              "thumbs3 main"
              "thumbs4 main"    
  ;
}

.item:first-child   { grid-area: main; }
.item:nth-child(2)  { grid-area: thumbs2; }
.item:nth-child(3)  { grid-area: thumbs3; }
.item:nth-child(4)  { grid-area: thumbs4; }

.item img {
 width: 100px;
 height: auto;
}

.item:first-child img {
 width: 200px;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="mygrid">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=info>MY TITLE</div>
  <div class=info>My Description</div>
  <div class=prijs>My Price</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e28mc4f5/5/)

Comment: Thank you Michael.  I came to a similar conclusion.  Thanks for explaining "the why" of it all.  i had - incorrectly - asumed a grid behaves like a div and you could just keep adding things to it and they would position themselves one after the other. (sorry, unable to vote you up, not enough rep)

Comment: *"i had - incorrectly - asumed a grid behaves like a div and you could just keep adding things to it and they would position themselves one after the other."* ... Your assumption is actually correct...

Comment: Grid has an [**auto-placement algorithm**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-auto-flow-property) which does just that, and you can control the flow of it, as well (`row`, `column`, `dense`)...

Comment: The problem occurs when you give one class of items the same grid area name.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found the reason for the weirdness.

In case anybody else runs into something similar:

The HTML elements that will be placed in the grid all need to be on the same level in the DOM and be a direct descendant of the grid-element.
When you have html elements in a html element in a grid element, you need to create a new grid element for the lower tier html elements.

Comment: I don't think this is the reason for the problem. But please post a working example with your solution to verify.

Comment: hello, i lack the reputation to add another link to my post.  This is the jsFiddle with my final solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/e28mc4f5/2/
I had to make a second grid for all the item-images in the items element.  And i had to manually set each image in it's own element.  because when i add them to the same element, they are placed over each other.  so i made thumbs1, thumbs2 and thumbs3 instead of one big thumbs area